# Alguém saber como fazer uma animação de background igual a esse site?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá, pessoal, segue abaixo o site:
http://8guild.com/

Alguém sabe como fazer esse background? Se tiver um tutorial eu agradeço, já procurei muito e não achei nada.

Answer (score 1):

A animação que está no site foi feita em *CSS*.

No exemplo abaixo criei uma animação similar.

O `keyframe` altera a posição vertical do *background* com o *pattern* aplicado e a linha `animation: animacao 15s infinite linear;` define a animação no `<body>`.

Você pode alterar os valores e ir testando para entender melhor como funciona.

```css
body {
  background: url('https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/tic-tac-toe.png');
  animation: animacao 30s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes animacao {
  50% {
    background-position: 0% 500%;
  }
  
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 1000%;
  }
}
```